# Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOU

Tags: email, meteor, smtp

Exception while invoking method 'forgotPassword' Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOU

ND
I20161024-13:37:32.563(5.75)?     at Object.Future.wait 
(/home/john/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.3.k
c10re++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibe
rs/future.js:449:15)

I20161024-13:37:32.564(5.75)?     at smtpSend (packages/email/email.js:89:1)

I20161024-13:37:32.564(5.75)?     at Object.Email.send (packages/email/email.js:192:1)

I20161024-13:37:32.564(5.75)?     at AccountsServer.Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail (packages/accounts-pa
ssword/password_server.js:577:9)

I20161024-13:37:32.564(5.75)?     at [object Object].forgotPassword (packages/accounts-password/password_
server.js:516:12)

I20161024-13:37:32.565(5.75)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:170
4:12)

I20161024-13:37:32.565(5.75)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:711:19

I20161024-13:37:32.565(5.75)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.
js:56:1)

I20161024-13:37:32.565(5.75)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:709:40

I20161024-13:37:32.566(5.75)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.
js:56:1)

I20161024-13:37:32.566(5.75)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:707:46

I20161024-13:37:32.567(5.75)?     at tryCallTwo (/home/john/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.7.2.1cuapq8++os+w
eb.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)

I20161024-13:37:32.567(5.75)?     at doResolve (/home/john/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.7.2.1cuapq8++os+we
b.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)

I20161024-13:37:32.567(5.75)?     at new Promise (/home/john/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.7.2.1cuapq8++os+
web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)

I20161024-13:37:32.567(5.75)?     at Session.method (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:681:23)

I20161024-13:37:32.568(5.75)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:551:43

I20161024-13:37:32.568(5.75)?     - - - - -

I20161024-13:37:32.568(5.75)?     at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)

I20161024-13:37:32.568(5.75)?     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:126:16)

Comment: Your body contains only server logs. Can you please explain what you did? At present, it's difficult to help without looking at your code.

Comment: actually i found the solution the password that i have passed was not according to the format , although thanks for your interest..